# Free body force diagram with 3 pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I am certain this has already been asked and answered, but I have not been able to find it.  It has been about 25 years since I last sat in a physics class, and some parts are a bit rusty!  I am planning to hang some heavy gear in my garage and am trying to determine the weight at each mounting point.  (Yes, I know I need to add in a large safety factor for overhead rigging).  I have tried to simplify the plan in the attached drawing (which I have learned is called a free body diagram!...you can teach an old dog new tricks!)
At point "A" the rope will be firmly fastened.  It then travels down to a series of 2 pulleys on my load (200 pounds for this example)...then back up to point "B" which is another pulley...and finally down to a crank on the wall @ point "C"

My basic understanding is that the 200# are split evenly between point A and B...each with 100# pulling down(ish) on them.  But then the wall crank ("C") is pulling presumably with 100#...which might then double the force at "B"?...or am I overthinking this?  I know things get trickier given that none of the lines are perfectly vertical, but I am just trying to get "close enough" in this case.

Seems like:

```
A = 100 pounds
B = 200 pounds??
c = 100 pounds
```

THANKS!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let T be the tension in the rope. The force acting on weight is 2T upwards. So T is half the weight of the box. Well I can't say T is 100lb as pound is unit of mass not force but anyways I hope you understand what I am trying to convey.

The hinge force at A is T, at B is 2T and at C is T; hence hinge forces are calculated accordingly.

Comment: So, just to clarify, my rough approximations are correct?A = 100 pounds
B = 200 pounds
c = 100 pounds